# Transformation of exponential distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

> $X\sim\operatorname{Exp}(a)$ and $Y\sim\operatorname{Exp}(b)$ are independent random variables. What are $P(X>Y)$ and $P(X>2Y)$?

I know the answers are $\frac a{a+b}$ and $\frac a{a+2b}$ respectively, but I don't know how to solve this. Somebody help me thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site. You are accumulating votes to close this question because you have not shown what you have tried. If you write out the double integral with limits and an explicit form of $f(x,y),$ that will show some engagement on your part, and maybe get you more explicit help if you still need it.

Answer (score 3):

The probabilities you want to know can be calculated as the integral of the joint distribution over a specific domain:
$$
\iint_D f(x,y)dydx.
$$
the difficulty is to find the domain you need. For the first question, a description of this domain would be $0\le x<\infty$ and $0\le y \le x$. Note that this is not the only way to describe this domain.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me some more clues?

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: I integrated the formula by y first and then x, but calculating this was very tricky. Do I have to integrate this formula by x first?

Comment: @JWKim Try out one of the ways. If you do not trust the result then try out the other way in the hope of a match. Good exercise!

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** Here is a simulation of the second part in R statistical software, based on
30,000 $(X, Y)$ pairs. I used $X \sim Exp(rate = 1/5)$ and $Y \sim Exp(rate = 1/3)$
so that $E(X) = 5$ and $E(Y) = 3.$ The approximation of $P(X > 2Y)$ would be
better with more points.

```
x = rexp(30000, 1/5);  y = rexp(30000, 1/3)
mean(x > 2*y)
## 0.4556667  # aprx P(X > 2Y) = 5/11
```

The main point of this demonstration is the figure below, in which the 13,670
points corresponding to the event $\{X > 2Y\}$ are shown in red. This may
help you set the limits on your integrals. The density of the points near
the origin indicates that the joint density function is relatively large there.

[image]